# Using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE inside PL\SQL Block

Tags: oracle, plsql, ddl, dml

Using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE inside PL\SQL block makes the whole block commit immediately.

```
begin 

INSERT INTO Customer ( GUID, STATUS, NAME) VALUES (1,1,'xx');

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE Shop
(
  GUID         NUMBER(16),
  STATUS       NUMBER(1),
  NAME         VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
)
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
NOPARALLEL
MONITORING';

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DONE:'); 

EXCEPTION  -- exception handlers begin 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN  -- handles all other errors 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error occured, rollback...'); 

 ROLLBACK;
end;
```

As you realized I do not even use COMMIT. About above code,

"Insert into" statement works, but "create table" statement throws exception because there is already a table with the same name in the database.

Both I did not have any commit statement and code block fell exception and rolled back when I looked at the database I saw that insert had worked and there was a new row. It was expected that it should not have been there because there is no commit and also rollback worked..

How can I make rollback when exception occurs.

Comment: Any DDL statement will commit a pending transaction regardless whether the DDL is successful or not. Oracle does not support transactional DDL.

Comment: Cross post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803601/using-execute-immediate-inside-pl-sql-block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle when you create a table or execute an alter statement there is an implied commit. You may want to create the table in a separate function returning a boolean value with "PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION"  then the calling procedure would get a true/false response as to whether or not the table was created. you will then be able to commit or rollback your insert.

Comment: Any DDL statement causes an implicit commit.  Not every `ALTER` statement, however, is DDL so not every `ALTER` statement does an implicit commit.  For example, `ALTER SESSION SET nls_date_format = ...` is an `ALTER` statement that is not DDL and that does not implicitly commit.

Comment: Right it needs to be DDL, as in alter table, alter index, etc.